# How To Using Intent Using the bet

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, intentservice

i have a Save Class page for save data class ,the page have a button for get data and send them to Database Class for save data then back to Main Page with using Intent Class.

The point is here in my Database i use Cursor for Check same Data so if Cursor found same data , data will not save.

Now my problem is that I want to go back to main page only when the data is saved But now if the data is saved or not(If there is duplicate data) , Returns to the main page

my code :

```
    public void SaveClass(View view)
{
    String className = className_EditeText.getText().toString();
    String uniName = uniName_EditeText.getText().toString();
    String classNumber = classNumber_EditText.getText().toString();

        database.OpenDatabase();
        database.SaveClass(className , classNumber , uniName);//SaveClass If Find Same Data Will Not Save 
        database.close();

        //I want to only when data is saved (intent run)

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this , MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);}
```

Comment: what db are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the save method (`database.SaveClass(className, classNumber, uniName)`) in you database class to return a `boolean` to indicate whether new data was added or not. If the data is new then insert it and return `true`. If the data already exists in the database then return `false`.

With this approach the code should look like this:

```
public void SaveClass(View view) {
    String className = className_EditeText.getText().toString();
    String uniName = uniName_EditeText.getText().toString();
    String classNumber = classNumber_EditText.getText().toString();

    database.OpenDatabase();
    boolean isNewClass = database.SaveClass(className, classNumber, uniName);
    database.close();

    if (isNewClass) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this , MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```